# How to create a table of wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database, sql-like

I have a table called `blacklisted_usernames`. These are usernames with wildcards in them that aren't allowed to be registered onto my site.

```
create table blacklisted_usernames (
name varchar(64) not null
);
```

Some dummy data:

```
insert into blacklisted_usernames (name) values
('%admin%'),
('king%'),
('bad'),
('%cool');
```

The `%` indicates the same thing as the wildcard in the `LIKE` function in MySQL. I want to create an efficient case insensitive query which tells me if a username is blacklisted or not. For example is the username `AdminJohn` allowed? The answer would be no, because of `%admin%` being in the `blacklisted_usernames` table.

I understand I can do something like

```
SELECT 1
WHERE 'AdminJohn' LIKE '%admin%'
or 'AdminJohn' LIKE 'king%'
or 'AdminJohn' LIKE 'bad'
or 'AdminJohn' LIKE '%cool'
```

But I am manually typing out all the LIKE's. I also don't think it would be efficient if I created a loop checking it 1 by 1. Is there a way I can make this into an automatic but efficient way of checking against the names in `blacklisted_usernames` table and determining if a username is allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use a REGEXP to test them all in a single test:

```
WHERE 'AdminJohn' REGEXP 'admin|^king|^bad$|cool$'
```

(Note how the wildcards go away on some and "anchors" are needed on the others.)

*Probably* this is faster than the original `OR`+`LIKEs` or the `JOIN`+`LIKEs`.  When checking one name `REGEXP` will be plenty fast (no table scan).

Answer (score 2):

```
select 1 from blacklisted_usernames where 'AdminJohn' like name limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check all existing names against the blacklisted patterns

```sql
SELECT usernames.name, 
       blacklisted_usernames.name blacklisted_pattern
FROM usernames
JOIN blacklisted_usernames 
    ON usernames.name LIKE blacklisted_usernames.name
```

Pay attention - this is complete tablescan, the indices won't be used, so the query will be slow.

You may need to check all existing names against newly added/altered patterns - in this case add according WHERE by `blacklisted_usernames` table (for example, by `created_at` or `updated_at` column).

If you need to check currently created username against all patterns then use [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72851977/10138734) provided by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth).